# Transparent text over a background?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have transparent text on top of a white background with an image behind it, so that the text appears to be the colour of the image behind it.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I started to give you a better understanding of what I mean:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/g3SfD/**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3SfD/)

Right now the text is black, but is there a way to make it transparent so that the colour of the text is that of the background image?

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Sample Text</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -219px;
    margin-top: -47.5px;

}

.image {
    background: url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 960px;
    height: 420px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you want to show the white area in the example but not the black text, like a mask.

Comment: Yeah, so that the text is transparent (ie, the background image can be seen through the text).

Comment: You can sort of fake it. See this example: http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/full/sCEHv/

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3SfD/3/)

Ok thanks to [this example](http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/full/sCEHv) provided by ralph.m, it seems possible using `-webkit-background-clip` which would only be supported by browsers that can use webkit.

```
.text {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    background-position: -200px -50px;
}
```

Your background size and position may need tweaking to suit.

Comment: you should add note about the support of this feature which is currently (maybe only) supported by webkit-based browsers. A cross-browser solution is not really someting easy to find.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you're looking for the rgba() function.
It takes 4 parameters, 3 colors channels and one alpha that controls the opacity of the color.

Comment: I know of rgba, but try applying it to my example.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question about how to make the box appear but not the text